# Best Repository and project management software

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Me and my team are looking to develop software, using a central server and Java EE. We wanted to set up a repository on that server so that we can each access the code and edit it on our local machines and then commit and deploy the code on the server.

I am wondering what the best way to do this would be? I have looked into gitstack and maven, but I am unsure on which would be the best route to take.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Its mostly a matter of opinion. There is no best only a best fit for a particular situation. Voting to close as there is no real answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickest way to get started is setup an account on GitHub, pay the fee for private repos, then setup a Jenkins / Hudson server to build your project and do continuous integration.

Best? That would depend on your business / project, more information is needed to determine which is best for your business / project.

Comment: `bitbucket` provides free private hosting

Answer (score 1):

I use `GitHub`. It has great documentation and is used by both large and small companies. You can select free or paid, depending on what you need for your situation. GitHub also has great API's for Mac or Windows, and can also be run from command line.

Another option is Perforce, but the companies that I have worked for that are using Perforce are getting ready to change to Git.